# Why don't the images align when concatenating two data sets in pytorch using torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, dataset

I wanted to concatenate multiple data sets where the labels are disjoint (so don't share labels). I did:

```
class ConcatDataset(Dataset):
    """

    ref: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/concat-image-datasets-with-different-size-and-number-of-channels/36362/12
    """

    def __init__(self, datasets: list[Dataset]):
        """
        """
        # I think concat is better than passing data to a self.data = x obj since concat likely using the getitem method of the passed dataset and thus if the passed dataset doesnt put all the data in memory concat won't either
        self.concat_datasets = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset(datasets)
        # maps a class label to a list of sample indices with that label.
        self.labels_to_indices = defaultdict(list)
        # maps a sample index to its corresponding class label.
        self.indices_to_labels = defaultdict(None)
        # - do the relabeling
        offset: int = 0
        new_idx: int = 0
        for dataset_idx, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
            assert len(dataset) == len(self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx])
            assert dataset == self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx]
            for x, y in dataset:
                y = int(y)
                _x, _y = self.concat_datasets[new_idx]
                _y = int(_y)
                # assert y == _y
                assert torch.equal(x, _x)
                new_label = y + offset
                self.indices_to_labels[new_idx] = new_label
                self.labels_to_indices[new_label] = new_idx
            num_labels_for_current_dataset: int = max([y for _, y in dataset])
            offset += num_labels_for_current_dataset
            new_idx += 1
        assert len(self.indices_to_labels.keys()) == len(self.concat_datasets)
        # contains the list of labels from 0 - total num labels after concat
        self.labels = range(offset)
        self.target_transform = lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.int)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.concat_datasets)

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> tuple[Tensor, Tensor]:
        x = self.concat_datasets[idx]
        y = self.indices_to_labels[idx]
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            y = self.target_transform(y)
        return x, y
```

but it doesn't even work to align the x images (so never mind if my relabling works!). Why?

```
def check_xs_align_cifar100():
    from pathlib import Path

    root = Path("~/data/").expanduser()
    # root = Path(".").expanduser()
    train = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=True, download=True)
    test = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=False, download=True)

    concat = ConcatDataset([train, test])
    print(f'{len(concat)=}')
    print(f'{len(concat.labels)=}')
```

error

```
Files already downloaded and verified
Files already downloaded and verified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1491, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/dataset/concate_dataset.py", line 405, in <module>
    check_xs_align()
  File "/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/dataset/concate_dataset.py", line 391, in check_xs_align
    concat = ConcatDataset([train, test])
  File "/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/dataset/concate_dataset.py", line 71, in __init__
    assert torch.equal(x, _x)
TypeError: equal(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not Image
python-BaseException
```

Bonus: let me know if relabeling is correct please.

related discussion: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/concat-image-datasets-with-different-size-and-number-of-channels/36362/12

---

## Edit 1: PIL comparison fails

I did a PIL image comparison according to [Compare images Python PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176639/compare-images-python-pil) but it failed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1491, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/dataset/concate_dataset.py", line 419, in <module>
    check_xs_align_cifar100()
  File "/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/dataset/concate_dataset.py", line 405, in check_xs_align_cifar100
    concat = ConcatDataset([train, test])
  File "/Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/dataset/concate_dataset.py", line 78, in __init__
    assert diff.getbbox(), f'comparison of imgs failed: {diff.getbbox()=}'
AssertionError: comparison of imgs failed: diff.getbbox()=None
python-BaseException
diff
PyDev console: starting.
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=32x32 at 0x7FBE897A21C0>
```

code comparison:

```
                diff = ImageChops.difference(x, _x)  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176639/compare-images-python-pil
                assert diff.getbbox(), f'comparison of imgs failed: {diff.getbbox()=}'
```

this also failed:

```
    assert list(x.getdata()) == list(_x.getdata()), f'\n{list(x.getdata())=}, \n{list(_x.getdata())=}'
AssertionError: ...long msg...
```

assert statement was:

```
                assert list(x.getdata()) == list(_x.getdata()), f'\n{list(x.getdata())=}, \n{list(_x.getdata())=}'
```

---

## Edit 2: Tensor comparison Fails

I tried to convert images to tensors but it still fails:

```
AssertionError: Error for some reason, got: data_idx=1, x.norm()=tensor(45.9401), _x.norm()=tensor(33.9407), x=tensor([[[1.0000, 0.9922, 0.9922,  ..., 0.9922, 0.9922, 1.0000],
```

code:

```
class ConcatDataset(Dataset):
    """
    ref:
        - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/concat-image-datasets-with-different-size-and-number-of-channels/36362/12
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913522/why-dont-the-images-align-when-concatenating-two-data-sets-in-pytorch-using-tor
    """

    def __init__(self, datasets: list[Dataset]):
        """
        """
        # I think concat is better than passing data to a self.data = x obj since concat likely using the getitem method of the passed dataset and thus if the passed dataset doesnt put all the data in memory concat won't either
        self.concat_datasets = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset(datasets)
        # maps a class label to a list of sample indices with that label.
        self.labels_to_indices = defaultdict(list)
        # maps a sample index to its corresponding class label.
        self.indices_to_labels = defaultdict(None)
        # - do the relabeling
        img2tensor: Callable = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
        offset: int = 0
        new_idx: int = 0
        for dataset_idx, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
            assert len(dataset) == len(self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx])
            assert dataset == self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx]
            for data_idx, (x, y) in enumerate(dataset):
                y = int(y)
                # - get data point from concataned data set (to compare with the data point from the data set list)
                _x, _y = self.concat_datasets[new_idx]
                _y = int(_y)
                # - sanity check concatanted data set aligns with the list of datasets
                # assert y == _y
                # from PIL import ImageChops
                # diff = ImageChops.difference(x, _x)  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176639/compare-images-python-pil
                # assert diff.getbbox(), f'comparison of imgs failed: {diff.getbbox()=}'
                # assert list(x.getdata()) == list(_x.getdata()), f'\n{list(x.getdata())=}, \n{list(_x.getdata())=}'
                # tensor comparison
                x, _x = img2tensor(x), img2tensor(_x)
                print(f'{data_idx=}, {x.norm()=}, {_x.norm()=}')
                assert torch.equal(x, _x), f'Error for some reason, got: {data_idx=}, {x.norm()=}, {_x.norm()=}, {x=}, {_x=}'
                # - relabling
                new_label = y + offset
                self.indices_to_labels[new_idx] = new_label
                self.labels_to_indices[new_label] = new_idx
            num_labels_for_current_dataset: int = max([y for _, y in dataset])
            offset += num_labels_for_current_dataset
            new_idx += 1
        assert len(self.indices_to_labels.keys()) == len(self.concat_datasets)
        # contains the list of labels from 0 - total num labels after concat
        self.labels = range(offset)
        self.target_transform = lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.int)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.concat_datasets)

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> tuple[Tensor, Tensor]:
        x = self.concat_datasets[idx]
        y = self.indices_to_labels[idx]
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            y = self.target_transform(y)
        return x, y
```

---

## Edit 3, clarification request:

My vision of the data set I want is a concatenation of a data sets in question -- where relabeling starting the first label commences. The curicial thing (according to me -- might be wrong on this) is that once concatenated we should verify in some way that the data set indeed behaves the way we want it. One check I thought is to index the data point from the list of data sets and also from the concatenation object of the data set. If the data set was correctly conatenated I'd expect the images to be correspond according to this indexing. So if the first image in the first data set had some unique identifier (e.g. the pixels) then the concatenation of the data sets should have the first image be the same as the first image in the list of data sets and so on...if this doesn't hold, if I start creating new labels -- how do I know I am even doing this correctly?

---

reddit link: https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/xurnu9/why_dont_the_images_align_when_concatenating_two/

cross posted pytorch discuss: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-dont-the-images-align-when-concatenating-two-data-sets-in-pytorch-using-torch-utils-data-concatdataset/162801?u=brando_miranda

Comment: @DialFrost it solved the tensor comparison but it didn't solve the fact the data sets arent aligned :(

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood but, can't you combine the data sets then to align them? (i.e. make them share labels)

Comment: Like first externally merge them you need? I suppose it's possible but the list of data set can be humongous like re organizing imagnet plus a bunch of other dataset

Comment: @DialFrost hi! thanks for the help. I made a 3rd edit. Let me know if that helps. If not I am happy to go into a chat discussion here on SO to clarify what I believe is the correct way to test if the concat/union of the data sets was done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code can be found here https://github.com/brando90/ultimate-utils/blob/master/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/dataset/concate_dataset.py you can pip install the library `pip install ultimate-utils`.

Since only links is not a good way to answer I will copy paste the code too with it's test and expected output:

```
"""

do checks, loop through all data points, create counts for each label how many data points there are
do this for MI only

then check union and ur implementation?
compare the mappings of one & the other?

actually it's easy, just add the cummulative offset and that's it. :D the indices are already -1 indexed.

assert every image has a label between 0 --> n1+n2+... and every bin for each class is none empty

for it to work with any standard pytorch data set I think the workflow would be:
```

pytorch dataset -> l2l meta data set -> union data set -> .dataset field -> data loader

```
for l2l data sets:
```

l2l meta data set -> union data set -> .dataset field -> data loader

```
but the last one might need to make sure .indices or .labels is created or a get labels function that checking the attribute
gets the right .labels or remaps it correctly
"""
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Callable, Optional

import torch
import torchvision
from torch import Tensor
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader


class ConcatDatasetMutuallyExclusiveLabels(Dataset):
    """
    Useful attributes:
        - self.labels: contains all new USL labels i.e. contains the list of labels from 0 - total num labels after concat.
        - len(self): gives number of images after all images have been concatenated
        - self.indices_to_labels: maps the new concat idx to the new label after concat.

    ref:
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913522/why-dont-the-images-align-when-concatenating-two-data-sets-in-pytorch-using-tor
        - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/concat-image-datasets-with-different-size-and-number-of-channels/36362/12
    """

    def __init__(self, datasets: list[Dataset],
                 transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
                 target_transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
                 compare_imgs_directly: bool = False,
                 verify_xs_align: bool = False,
                 ):
        """
        Concatenates different data sets assuming the labels are mutually exclusive in the data sets.

        compare_imgs_directly: adds the additional test that imgs compare at the PIL imgage level.
        """
        self.datasets = datasets
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform
        # I think concat is better than passing data to a self.data = x obj since concat likely using the getitem method of the passed dataset and thus if the passed dataset doesnt put all the data in memory concat won't either
        self.concat_datasets = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset(datasets)
        # maps a class label to a list of sample indices with that label.
        self.labels_to_indices = defaultdict(list)
        # maps a sample index to its corresponding class label.
        self.indices_to_labels = defaultdict(None)
        # - do the relabeling
        self._re_label_all_dataset(datasets, compare_imgs_directly, verify_xs_align)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.concat_datasets)

    def _re_label_all_dataset(self, datasets: list[Dataset],
                              compare_imgs_directly: bool = False,
                              verify_xs_align: bool = False,
                              ):
        """
        Relabels according to a blind (mutually exclusive) assumption.

        Relabling Algorithm:
        The zero index of the label starts at the number of labels collected so far. So when relabling we do:
            y =  y + total_number_labels
            total_number_labels += max label for current data set
        where total_number_labels always has the + 1 to correct for the zero indexing.

        :param datasets:
        :param compare_imgs_directly:
        :parm verify_xs_align: set to false by default in case your transforms aren't deterministic.
        :return:
        """
        self.img2tensor: Callable = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
        self.int2tensor: Callable = lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.int)
        total_num_labels_so_far: int = 0
        new_idx: int = 0
        for dataset_idx, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
            assert len(dataset) == len(self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx])
            assert dataset == self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx]
            for data_idx, (x, y) in enumerate(dataset):
                y = int(y)
                # - get data point from concataned data set (to compare with the data point from the data set list)
                _x, _y = self.concat_datasets[new_idx]
                _y = int(_y)
                # - sanity check concatanted data set aligns with the list of datasets
                assert y == _y
                if compare_imgs_directly:
                    # from PIL import ImageChops
                    # diff = ImageChops.difference(x, _x)  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176639/compare-images-python-pil
                    # assert diff.getbbox(), f'comparison of imgs failed: {diff.getbbox()=}' # doesn't work :/
                    assert list(x.getdata()) == list(_x.getdata()), f'\n{list(x.getdata())=}, \n{list(_x.getdata())=}'
                    # tensor comparison
                if not isinstance(x, Tensor):
                    x, _x = self.img2tensor(x), self.img2tensor(_x)
                if isinstance(y, int):
                    y, _y = self.int2tensor(y), self.int2tensor(_y)
                if verify_xs_align:
                    # this might fails if there are random ops in the getitem
                    assert torch.equal(x,
                                       _x), f'Error for some reason, got: {dataset_idx=},' \
                                            f' {new_idx=}, {data_idx=}, ' \
                                            f'{x.norm()=}, {_x.norm()=}, ' \
                                            f'{x=}, {_x=}'
                # - relabling
                new_label = y + total_num_labels_so_far
                self.indices_to_labels[new_idx] = new_label
                self.labels_to_indices[new_label].append(new_idx)
                new_idx += 1
            num_labels_for_current_dataset: int = int(max([y for _, y in dataset])) + 1
            # - you'd likely resolve unions if you wanted a proper union, the addition assumes mutual exclusivity
            total_num_labels_so_far += num_labels_for_current_dataset
        assert len(self.indices_to_labels.keys()) == len(self.concat_datasets)
        # contains the list of labels from 0 - total num labels after concat, assume mutually exclusive
        self.labels = range(total_num_labels_so_far)

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> tuple[Tensor, Tensor]:
        """
        Get's the data point and it's new label according to a mutually exclusive concatenation.

        For later?
        to do the relabling on the fly we'd need to figure out which data set idx corresponds to and to compute the
        total_num_labels_so_far. Something like this:
            current_data_set_idx = bisect_left(idx)
            total_num_labels_so_far = sum(max(_, y in dataset)+1 for dataset_idx, dataset in enumerate(self.datasets) if dataset_idx <= current_data_set_idx)
            new_y = total_num_labels_so_far
            self.indices_to_labels[idx] = new_y
        :param idx:
        :return:
        """
        x, _y = self.concat_datasets[idx]
        y = self.indices_to_labels[idx]
        # for the first data set they aren't re-labaled so can't use assert
        # assert y != _y, f'concat dataset returns x, y so the y is not relabeled, but why are they the same {_y}, {y=}'
        # idk what this is but could be useful? mnist had this.
        # img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode="L")
        if self.transform is not None:
            x = self.transform(x)
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            y = self.target_transform(y)
        return x, y


def assert_dataset_is_pytorch_dataset(datasets: list, verbose: bool = False):
    """ to do 1 data set wrap it in a list"""
    for dataset in datasets:
        if verbose:
            print(f'{type(dataset)=}')
            print(f'{type(dataset.dataset)=}')
        assert isinstance(dataset, Dataset), f'Expect dataset to be of type Dataset but got {type(dataset)=}.'


def get_relabling_counts(dataset: Dataset) -> dict:
    """
    counts[new_label] -> counts/number of data points for that new label
    """
    assert isinstance(dataset, Dataset), f'Expect dataset to be of type Dataset but got {type(dataset)=}.'
    counts: dict = {}
    iter_dataset = iter(dataset)
    for datapoint in iter_dataset:
        x, y = datapoint
        # assert isinstance(x, torch.Tensor)
        # assert isinstance(y, int)
        if y not in counts:
            counts[y] = 0
        else:
            counts[y] += 1
    return counts


def assert_relabling_counts(counts: dict, labels: int = 100, counts_per_label: int = 600):
    """
    default values are for MI.

    - checks each label/class has the right number of expected images per class
    - checks the relabels start from 0 and increase by 1
    - checks the total number of labels after concat is what you expect

    ref: https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJY0-Kcll
    Because the exact splits used in Vinyals et al. (2016)
    were not released, we create our own version of the Mini-Imagenet dataset by selecting a random
    100 classes from ImageNet and picking 600 examples of each class. We use 64, 16, and 20 classes
    for training, validation and testing, respectively.
    """
    # - check each image has the right number of total images
    seen_labels: list[int] = []
    for label, count in counts.items():
        seen_labels.append(label)
        assert counts[label] == counts_per_label
    # - check all labels are there and total is correct
    seen_labels.sort()
    prev_label = -1
    for label in seen_labels:
        diff = label - prev_label
        assert diff == 1
        assert prev_label < label
    # - checks the final label is the total number of labels
    assert label == labels - 1


def check_entire_data_via_the_dataloader(dataloader: DataLoader) -> dict:
    counts: dict = {}
    for it, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
        xs, ys = batch
        for y in ys:
            if y not in counts:
                counts[y] = 0
            else:
                counts[y] += 1
    return counts


# - tests

def check_xs_align_mnist():
    root = Path('~/data/').expanduser()
    import torchvision
    # - test 1, imgs (not the recommended use)
    train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root=root, train=True, download=True)
    test = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root=root, train=False, download=True)
    concat = ConcatDatasetMutuallyExclusiveLabels([train, test], compare_imgs_directly=True)
    print(f'{len(concat)=}')
    print(f'{len(concat.labels)=}')
    # - test 2, tensor imgs
    train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root=root, train=True, download=True,
                                       transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       target_transform=lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.int))
    test = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root=root, train=False, download=True,
                                      transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                      target_transform=lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.int))
    concat = ConcatDatasetMutuallyExclusiveLabels([train, test], verify_xs_align=True)
    print(f'{len(concat)=}')
    print(f'{len(concat.labels)=}')
    assert len(concat) == 10 * 7000, f'Err, unexpected number of datapoints {len(concat)=} expected {100 * 700}'
    assert len(
        concat.labels) == 20, f'Note it should be 20 (since it is not a true union), but got {len(concat.labels)=}'

    # - test dataloader
    loader = DataLoader(concat)
    for batch in loader:
        x, y = batch
        assert isinstance(x, torch.Tensor)
        assert isinstance(y, torch.Tensor)


def check_xs_align_cifar100():
    from pathlib import Path
    root = Path('~/data/').expanduser()
    import torchvision
    # - test 1, imgs (not the recommended use)
    train = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=True, download=True)
    test = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=False, download=True)
    concat = ConcatDatasetMutuallyExclusiveLabels([train, test], compare_imgs_directly=True)
    print(f'{len(concat)=}')
    print(f'{len(concat.labels)=}')
    # - test 2, tensor imgs
    train = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=True, download=True,
                                          transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                          target_transform=lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.int))
    test = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=False, download=True,
                                         transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                         target_transform=lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.int))
    concat = ConcatDatasetMutuallyExclusiveLabels([train, test], verify_xs_align=True)
    print(f'{len(concat)=}')
    print(f'{len(concat.labels)=}')
    assert len(concat) == 100 * 600, f'Err, unexpected number of datapoints {len(concat)=} expected {100 * 600}'
    assert len(
        concat.labels) == 200, f'Note it should be 200 (since it is not a true union), but got {len(concat.labels)=}'
    # details on cifar100: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html

    # - test dataloader
    loader = DataLoader(concat)
    for batch in loader:
        x, y = batch
        assert isinstance(x, torch.Tensor)
        assert isinstance(y, torch.Tensor)


def concat_data_set_mi():
    """
    note test had to be in MI where train, val, test have disjount/different labels. In cifar100 classic the labels
    in train, val and test are shared from 0-99 instead of being different/disjoint.
    :return:
    """
    # - get mi data set
    from diversity_src.dataloaders.hdb1_mi_omniglot_l2l import get_mi_datasets
    train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset = get_mi_datasets()
    assert_dataset_is_pytorch_dataset([train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset])
    train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset = train_dataset.dataset, validation_dataset.dataset, test_dataset.dataset
    # - create usl data set
    union = ConcatDatasetMutuallyExclusiveLabels([train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset])
    # union = ConcatDatasetMutuallyExclusiveLabels([train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset],
    #                                              compare_imgs_directly=True)
    assert_dataset_is_pytorch_dataset([union])
    assert len(union) == 100 * 600, f'got {len(union)=}'
    assert len(union.labels) == 100, f'got {len(union.labels)=}'

    # - create dataloader
    from uutils.torch_uu.dataloaders.common import get_serial_or_distributed_dataloaders
    union_loader, _ = get_serial_or_distributed_dataloaders(train_dataset=union, val_dataset=union)
    for batch in union_loader:
        x, y = batch
        assert x is not None
        assert y is not None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    from uutils import report_times

    start = time.time()
    # - run experiment
    check_xs_align_mnist()
    check_xs_align_cifar100()
    concat_data_set_mi()
    # - Done
    print(f"\nSuccess Done!: {report_times(start)}\a")
```

expected correct output:

```
len(concat)=70000
len(concat.labels)=20
len(concat)=70000
len(concat.labels)=20
Files already downloaded and verified
Files already downloaded and verified
len(concat)=60000
len(concat.labels)=200
Files already downloaded and verified
Files already downloaded and verified
len(concat)=60000
len(concat.labels)=200
Success Done!: time passed: hours:0.16719497998555502, minutes=10.0316987991333, seconds=601.901927947998
```

warning:

> if you have a transform that is random the verification that the data sets align might make it look as if the two data points are not algined. The code is correct so it's not an issue, but perhaps remove the randomness somehow. Note, I actually decided to not force the user to check all the images of their data set and trust my code works from running once my unit tests. Also note that it's slow to construct the data set since I do the re-labling at the beginning. Might be better to relabel on the fly. I outlined the code for it on how to do it but decided against it since we always see all the data set at least once so doing this amortized is the same as doing it on the fly (note the fly pseudo-code saves the labels to avoid recomputations).

---

This is better:

```
# int2tensor: Callable = lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.int)
int2tensor: Callable = lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.long)


class ConcatDatasetMutuallyExclusiveLabels(Dataset):
    """
    Useful attributes:
        - self.labels: contains all new USL labels i.e. contains the list of labels from 0 - total num labels after concat.
        - len(self): gives number of images after all images have been concatenated
        - self.indices_to_labels: maps the new concat idx to the new label after concat.

    ref:
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913522/why-dont-the-images-align-when-concatenating-two-data-sets-in-pytorch-using-tor
        - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/concat-image-datasets-with-different-size-and-number-of-channels/36362/12
    """

    def __init__(self, datasets: list[Dataset],
                 transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
                 target_transform: Optional[Callable] = None,
                 compare_imgs_directly: bool = False,
                 verify_xs_align: bool = False,
                 ):
        """
        Concatenates different data sets assuming the labels are mutually exclusive in the data sets.

        compare_imgs_directly: adds the additional test that imgs compare at the PIL imgage level.
        """
        self.datasets = datasets
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform
        # I think concat is better than passing data to a self.data = x obj since concat likely using the getitem method of the passed dataset and thus if the passed dataset doesnt put all the data in memory concat won't either
        self.concat_datasets = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset(datasets)
        # maps a class label to a list of sample indices with that label.
        self.labels_to_indices = defaultdict(list)
        # maps a sample index to its corresponding class label.
        self.indices_to_labels = defaultdict(None)
        # - do the relabeling
        self._re_label_all_dataset(datasets, compare_imgs_directly, verify_xs_align)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.concat_datasets)

    def _re_label_all_dataset(self, datasets: list[Dataset],
                              compare_imgs_directly: bool = False,
                              verify_xs_align: bool = False,
                              verbose: bool = False,
                              ):
        """
        Relabels according to a blind (mutually exclusive) assumption.

        Relabling Algorithm:
        The zero index of the label starts at the number of labels collected so far. So when relabling we do:
            y =  y + total_number_labels
            total_number_labels += max label for current data set
        where total_number_labels always has the + 1 to correct for the zero indexing.

        assumption: it re-lables the data points to have a concatenation of all the labels. If there are rebeated labels
        they are treated as different. So if dataset1 and dataset2 both have cats (represented as indices), then they
        will get unique integers representing these. So the cats are treated as entirely different labels.
        """
        print()
        self.img2tensor: Callable = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
        total_num_labels_so_far: int = 0
        global_idx: int = 0  # new_idx
        assert len(self.indices_to_labels.keys()) == 0
        assert len(self.labels_to_indices.keys()) == 0
        for dataset_idx, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
            print(f'{dataset_idx=} \n{len(dataset)=}')
            if hasattr(dataset, 'labels'):
                print(f'{len(dataset.labels)=}')
            assert len(dataset) == len(self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx])
            assert dataset == self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx]
            original_label2global_idx: defaultdict = defaultdict(list)
            for original_data_idx, (x, original_y) in enumerate(dataset):
                original_y = int(original_y)
                # - get data point from concataned data set (to compare with the data point from the data set list)
                _x, _y = self.concat_datasets[global_idx]
                _y = int(_y)
                # - sanity check concatanted data set aligns with the list of datasets
                assert original_y == _y, f'{original_y=}, {_y=}'
                if compare_imgs_directly:
                    # from PIL import ImageChops
                    # diff = ImageChops.difference(x, _x)  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176639/compare-images-python-pil
                    # assert diff.getbbox(), f'comparison of imgs failed: {diff.getbbox()=}' # doesn't work :/
                    assert list(x.getdata()) == list(_x.getdata()), f'\n{list(x.getdata())=}, \n{list(_x.getdata())=}'
                # - tensor comparison of raw images
                if not isinstance(x, Tensor):
                    x, _x = self.img2tensor(x), self.img2tensor(_x)
                # if isinstance(original_y, int):
                #     original_y, _y = int2tensor(original_y), int2tensor(_y)
                if verify_xs_align:  # checks the data points after doing get item make them match.
                    # this might fails if there are random ops in the getitem
                    assert torch.equal(x,
                                       _x), f'Error for some reason, got: {dataset_idx=},' \
                                            f' {global_idx=}, {original_data_idx=}, ' \
                                            f'{x.norm()=}, {_x.norm()=}, ' \
                                            f'{x=}, {_x=}'
                # - collect original labels in dictionary keys
                original_label2global_idx[int(original_y)].append(global_idx)
                global_idx += 1
            print(f'{global_idx=}')
            local_num_dps: int = sum(len(global_indices) for global_indices in original_label2global_idx.values())
            assert len(dataset) == local_num_dps, f'Error: \n{local_num_dps=} \n{len(dataset)=}'
            # - do relabeling - original labeling to new global labels
            print(f'{total_num_labels_so_far=}')
            assert total_num_labels_so_far != len(dataset), f'Err:\n{total_num_labels_so_far=}\n{len(dataset)=}'
            new_local_label2global_indices: dict = {}
            global_label2global_indices: dict = {}
            # make sure to sort to avoid random looping of unordered data structures e.g. keys in a dict
            for new_local_label, original_label in enumerate(sorted(original_label2global_idx.keys())):
                global_indices: list[int] = original_label2global_idx[original_label]
                new_local_label2global_indices[int(new_local_label)] = global_indices
                new_global_label: int = total_num_labels_so_far + new_local_label
                global_label2global_indices[int(new_global_label)] = global_indices
            local_num_dps: int = sum(len(global_indices) for global_indices in original_label2global_idx.values())
            assert len(dataset) == local_num_dps, f'Error: \n{local_num_dps=} \n{len(dataset)=}'
            local_num_dps: int = sum(len(global_indices) for global_indices in new_local_label2global_indices.values())
            assert len(dataset) == local_num_dps, f'Error: \n{local_num_dps=} \n{len(dataset)=}'
            local_num_dps: int = sum(len(global_indices) for global_indices in global_label2global_indices.values())
            assert len(dataset) == local_num_dps, f'Error: \n{local_num_dps=} \n{len(dataset)=}'
            # - this assumes the integers in each data set is different, if there were unions you'd likely need semantic information about the label e.g. the string cat instead of absolute integers, or know the integers are shared between the two data sets
            print(f'{total_num_labels_so_far=}')
            # this is the step where classes are concatenated. Note due to the previous loops assuming each label is uning this should never have intersecting keys.
            print(f'{list(self.labels_to_indices.keys())=}')
            print(f'{list(global_label2global_indices.keys())=}')
            dup: list = get_duplicates(list(self.labels_to_indices.keys()) + list(global_label2global_indices.keys()))
            print(f'{list(self.labels_to_indices.keys())=}')
            print(f'{list(global_label2global_indices.keys())=}')
            assert len(dup) == 0, f'Error:\n{self.labels_to_indices.keys()=}\n{global_label2global_indices.keys()=}\n{dup=}'
            for global_label, global_indices in global_label2global_indices.items():
                # note g_idx might different to global_idx!
                global_indices: list[int]
                for g_idx in global_indices:
                    self.labels_to_indices[int(global_label)] = g_idx
                    self.indices_to_labels[g_idx] = int(global_label)
            # - update number of labels seen so far
            num_labels_for_current_dataset: int = len(original_label2global_idx.keys())
            print(f'{num_labels_for_current_dataset=}')
            total_num_labels_so_far += num_labels_for_current_dataset
            assert total_num_labels_so_far == len(self.labels_to_indices.keys()), f'Err:\n{total_num_labels_so_far=}' \
                                                                                  f'\n{len(self.labels_to_indices.keys())=}'
            assert global_idx == len(self.indices_to_labels.keys()), f'Err:\n{global_idx=}\n{len(self.indices_to_labels.keys())=}'
            if hasattr(dataset, 'labels'):
                assert len(dataset.labels) == num_labels_for_current_dataset, f'Err:\n{len(dataset.labels)=}' \
                                                                              f'\n{num_labels_for_current_dataset=}'
        # - relabling done
        assert len(self.indices_to_labels.keys()) == len(
            self.concat_datasets), f'Err: \n{len(self.indices_to_labels.keys())=}' \
                                   f'\n {len(self.concat_datasets)=}'
        if all(hasattr(dataset, 'labels') for dataset in datasets):
            assert sum(len(dataset.labels) for dataset in datasets) == total_num_labels_so_far
        # contains the list of labels from 0 - total num labels after concat, assume mutually exclusive
        # - set & validate new labels
        self.labels = range(total_num_labels_so_far)
        labels = list(sorted(list(self.labels_to_indices.keys())))
        assert labels == list(labels), f'labels should match and be consecutive, but got: \n{labels=}, \n{self.labels=}'

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> tuple[Tensor, Tensor]:
        """
        Get's the data point and it's new label according to a mutually exclusive concatenation.

        For later?
        to do the relabling on the fly we'd need to figure out which data set idx corresponds to and to compute the
        total_num_labels_so_far. Something like this:
            current_data_set_idx = bisect_left(idx)
            total_num_labels_so_far = sum(max(_, y in dataset)+1 for dataset_idx, dataset in enumerate(self.datasets) if dataset_idx <= current_data_set_idx)
            new_y = total_num_labels_so_far + y
            self.indices_to_labels[idx] = new_y
        :param idx:
        :return:
        """
        x, _y = self.concat_datasets[idx]
        y = self.indices_to_labels[idx]
        # for the first data set they aren't re-labaled so can't use assert
        # assert y != _y, f'concat dataset returns x, y so the y is not relabeled, but why are they the same {_y}, {y=}'
        # idk what this is but could be useful? mnist had this.
        # img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode="L")
        if self.transform is not None:
            x = self.transform(x)
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            y = self.target_transform(y)
        return x, y
```

Comment: use this answer!

Answer (score 2):

You are concatenating two `ImageFolder` datasets, `CIFAR10` and `CIFAR100`. Their default `__getitem__` returns `PIL.Image` object and *not* a tensor. Therefore, you cannot use `torch.equal` to compare two `PIL.Image` objects.

Try instead:

```py
train = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=True, download=True,  
                                      transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor())
test = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=False, download=True,  
                                     transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor())

concat = ConcatDataset([train, test])
```

Adding the `transform` will convert the `PIL.Image` returned by the dataset to a `torch.tensor` and will allow you to use `torch.equal` in your code.

Comment: ok, I first tried a PIL image comparison and it failed (see edits to question). Weird. Will report on tensor comparison in a second.

Comment: ok, the tensor comparison also fails, odd? `assert torch.equal(x, _x)` -- details in question edit 2.

Comment: for future readers, to see the fully corrected code see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I leave my original answer unchanged as it answers your question.

You have a tiny bug in your code that causes all the issues: you do not increment `new_idx` in the inner loop. As a result you keep comparing elements drawn directly from `dataset` to the *first* element of the corresponding dataset in `self.concat_datasets`.

New code that works:

```py
class ConcatDataset(Dataset):
    """
    ref:
        - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/concat-image-datasets-with-different-size-and-number-of-channels/36362/12
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913522/why-dont-the-images-align-when-concatenating-two-data-sets-in-pytorch-using-tor
    """

    def __init__(self, datasets: list[Dataset]):
        """
        """
        # I think concat is better than passing data to a self.data = x obj since concat likely using the getitem method of the passed dataset and thus if the passed dataset doesnt put all the data in memory concat won't either
        self.concat_datasets = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset(datasets)
        # maps a class label to a list of sample indices with that label.
        self.labels_to_indices = defaultdict(list)
        # maps a sample index to its corresponding class label.
        self.indices_to_labels = defaultdict(None)
        # - do the relabeling
        img2tensor: Callable = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
        offset: int = 0
        new_idx: int = 0
        for dataset_idx, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
            assert len(dataset) == len(self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx])
            assert dataset == self.concat_datasets.datasets[dataset_idx]
            for data_idx, (x, y) in enumerate(dataset):
                y = int(y)
                # - get data point from concataned data set (to compare with the data point from the data set list)
                _x, _y = self.concat_datasets[new_idx]
                _y = int(_y)
                # - sanity check concatanted data set aligns with the list of datasets
                # assert y == _y
                # from PIL import ImageChops
                # diff = ImageChops.difference(x, _x)  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176639/compare-images-python-pil
                # assert diff.getbbox(), f'comparison of imgs failed: {diff.getbbox()=}'
                # assert list(x.getdata()) == list(_x.getdata()), f'\n{list(x.getdata())=}, \n{list(_x.getdata())=}'
                # tensor comparison
                x, _x = img2tensor(x), img2tensor(_x)
                print(f'{data_idx=}, {x.norm()=}, {_x.norm()=}')
                assert torch.equal(x, _x), f'Error for some reason, got: {data_idx=}, {x.norm()=}, {_x.norm()=}, {x=}, {_x=}'
                # - relabling
                new_label = y + offset
                self.indices_to_labels[new_idx] = new_label
                self.labels_to_indices[new_label] = new_idx
                # increment here!!
                new_idx += 1   # need to increment inside the inner loop
                #
            num_labels_for_current_dataset: int = max([y for _, y in dataset])
            offset += num_labels_for_current_dataset
            # new_idx += 1  <-- THIS IS NOT THE RIGHT PLACE TO INCREMENT!
        assert len(self.indices_to_labels.keys()) == len(self.concat_datasets)
        # contains the list of labels from 0 - total num labels after concat
        self.labels = range(offset)
        self.target_transform = lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.int)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.concat_datasets)

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> tuple[Tensor, Tensor]:
        x = self.concat_datasets[idx]
        y = self.indices_to_labels[idx]
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            y = self.target_transform(y)
        return x, y
```

Comment: my code still has bugs, but I will post an answer to address all issues. Thanks for everything! You can keep the accepted answer ;)